# Pull on a git repository after a rebase was made

Tags: git, rebase

My team mates love to `git rebase` while working on our project together. When i try to update a branch with a `git pull` after, it usually fails with merge conflicts.

So, to help myself, I tended to reset the branch with `git reset --hard origin/...` which doesn't seem to be a nice workflow.

What is the best approach to adapt the changes in the way it was meant to be?

Comment: You can usually `git pull -r` to rebase your local commits onto whatever's been added to the remote branch. You can configure this to be the default: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your goal is to keep a linear commit history. What you could do is to fetch the remote changes on the branch and then rebase your local changes onto the remote changes.

You could use `git pull --rebase` to achieve that in one command by fetching the remote changes and rebasing your local changes onto them.

You might encounter merge conflicts, but after resolving these, you keep a linear commit history.

**Below the line is a more detailed explanation.**

---

The `git pull --rebase` command is a shortcut for the following:

I will assume the name of the branch is: `master` and the name of the remote is: `origin`.

You would first fetch the remote:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you can rebase your local changes onto the remote changes. Run the following command while on the `master` branch:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

I would recommend watching the following explanation by **Dan Gitschooldude** (Can recommend the whole series):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzagfGeFUuA&list=PLu-nSsOS6FRIg52MWrd7C_qSnQp3ZoHwW&index=19